# Python Flask : url_for to pass the variable to function from form template

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I tried this approach to pass the form input variable to function via url_for method. But its not working. can anyone check and let me know whats wrong in this code.

**Function:**

```
@app.route('/report_data/<year>/<week>', methods = ['POST'])
def report_data(year,week):
  print year
  print woy
```

**HTML Code :**

```
 <html>
<body>
   <form action="{{  url_for('report_data', year=n_year, week=n_woy) }}" method="post">
        <h3> Enter the details  </h3>
        Year :
        <input type="text" name="n_year"> <br>
        <br>
        Week :
        <input type="text" name="n_woy"> <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <br>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Issue:
Getting **"None"** for both variable.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, How do you provide year, week values before submitting them in your HTML code ?
Did you render the HTML template in your function? If not, how does your flask function knows that you were seeking from that specific form?

If this is your Flask app code -

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/report_data', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def report_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form
        query_year = result['n_year'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        query_week = result['n_woy'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        print(query_year, query_week)
    return render_template('so_test.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

And opened the URL -

> http://127.0.0.1:5000/report_data

And I get this picture. 
[image]

Once I post the data, I can see this data in my Flask app console.

> ('2018','08')